# Loop over a dictionary efficiently

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the form: `{'p0': -1.0, 'p1': -9.73133548174993, 'p2': 0.0306594941614714, 'p3': 2.0, 'p4': 0.514879452523938}` (much longer than this), and some expressions strings containing p0, p1 ... such as `p0*x+p1**2+p3+1`. I want to replace each instance of a parameter `pi` with its value in the dictionary. Is there a fast way to do this (in which I don't just use a for loop and .replace() for the string)? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason to not just store them in a list/array and use indexing, if the keys are all just `'p0', 'p1'` etc.? Obviously you can use indexing to extract the values from the `dict`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the "expression string"? Do you need to compute the value, or just show the equation with the values substituted, or just what? What exactly is your desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this would likely be with the `str.format_map()` method, although this will require the replaced elements to be surrounded in curly brackets, so if you have no way to make sure that your input data will have that, you're going to have to separately replace it anyway.

```
>>> in_str = '{p0}*x+{p1}**2+{p3}+1'
>>> vals = {'p0': -1.0, 'p1': -9.73133548174993, 'p2': 0.0306594941614714, 'p3': 2.0, 'p4': 0.514879452523938}
>>> in_str.format_map(vals)
-1.0*x+-9.73133548174993**2+2.0+1
```

Comment: The string would still need to be evaluated. Might as well just change the equations to use the dict directly if you are going to put the effort into adding curly braces anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use something like [format_map()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-format_map/) to do this? If I understand correctly

```
# input stored in variable a. 
a = {'x':'John', 'y':'Wick'} 

# Use of format_map() function 
print("{x}'s last name is {y}".format_map(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite the equations to use a dictionary

```
def func(d, x):
    return d['p0']*x+d['p1']**2+d['p3']+1
```

Or you could use `eval` using the dict as a namespace

```
def p_func_eval(data, x):
    return eval('p0*x+p1**2+p3+1', None, data)
    
data = {'p0': -1.0, 'p1': -9.73133548174993, 'p2': 0.0306594941614714, 'p3': 2.0, 'p4': 0.514879452523938}

print(func(data, 33))
```

The second method needs to reparse the string every time so may be a bit slower than the first. You could precompile the expressions or cache them as you go. This is a bit more complicated and only makes a difference if you do it alot.

```
_p_func_cache = {}

def p_fun_eval(expression, data, x):
    if expression not in _p_func_cache:
        _p_func_cache[expression] = compile(expression, 'p_func', 'eval')
    return eval(_p_func_cache[expression], None, data)
```

Comment: The question asks to replace the parameters in the string with those in the dictionary, so unless they were just doing this to evaluate the answer, neither of these methods would answer the question.

Comment: @duckboycool - And notice that OP has failed to answer the question of whether the expression is to be evaluated. We have to make guesses when questions are not complete. If OP plans to evaluate the expression, this is the best answer posted.

Comment: They accepted an answer which only did the replacing, so I'm thinking they didn't want to evaluate.

Comment: @duckboycool - So what? This is a good way to solve this type of problem. OP doesn't want it, okay. This is for the other 99%.

Answer (score 2):

You have two good answers here (so far) using format_map.  Now you just need a regex to to replace all your p# or p## or p### values with {} around them (as in {p#} in their answers):

```
import re
formula = "p0*x+p1**2+p33+1"
new_formula = re.sub(r"(p\d*)",r"{\1}",formula)
print (new_formula)
```

Comment: This is fragile - suppose two years from now the new guy adds parameter "r3" to the mix without knowing there is a function expanding the string like this?

Comment: @tdelaney There is no support for your concern.  Certainly p stands for parameter followed by an index.  Why would that convention change?  Ever?  Reread the original question.

Comment: Oh please. You don't think that a program that has p values today couldn't have r values tomorrow? We don't know what these things are. They are just keys in a dictionary.

Comment: Yes I did read the question. I said your method is fragile and explained why. A minor change in what's being fed in results in a bug. I wouldn't accept this in a code review. And considering that the string still needs `eval`, what was the point of reformatting it anyway?

Comment: So, replacing `p` in the regex pattern with `[A-Za-z]` would make you happy? I don't like eval either, so the op should probably use `ast.literal_eval()` from the `ast` module.

Comment: `eval` can be safe. Just fill in the globals and locals parameters and you control the execution environment for the expression. You can add functions to the globals if you want to expose, say, functions in `math`. `exec` is a different matter completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
d={'p0': -1.0, 'p1': -9.73133548174993, 'p2': 0.0306594941614714, 'p3': 2.0, 'p4': 0.514879452523938}
for k,v in d.items():
    locals()[k]=v        # or vars()[k]=v  or globals()[k]=v
#each keys in d is converted into variables whose values is corresponding d.values()
print(p0,p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
equation="p0*x+p1**2+p3+1"
mydict={'p0': -1.0, 'p1': -9.73133548174993, 'p2': 0.0306594941614714, 'p3': 2.0, 
'p4': 0.514879452523938}

for k,v in mydict.items():
    equation=re.sub(str(k),str(v),equation)

print(equation)
```

output:

```
-1.0*x+-9.73133548174993**2+2.0+1
```